# Converting string to JSON in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, json, string, json.net

I have done some operation on my ASP.NET page and stored its result in a string(with multiple lines) now I want to store that string in JSON format so that I can use it later on.
I am using JSON.NET (Newtonsoft) for this purpose. Please help me out how can I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JsonConvert.SerializeObject and JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

```
//some c# class -- let me know if you're using vb.net and I can translate accordingly
public class MyAwesomeClass {
    public int MyAwesomeProperty {get;set;}
}

//instantiate an instance of my c# class
MyAwesomeClass csharpobj = new MyAwesomeClass() { MyAwesomeProperty = 12 };

//serialize the object into json. the "json" variable will look something like "{ MyAwesomeProperty: 12 }"
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myCSharpObject);

//now convert the json back into a c# object--note the Type definition in between the '<>'--this tells the method what c# type to convert the json string to 
MyAwesomeClass csharpobjBackFromTheJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyAwesomeClass>(json);
```

Comment: can you explain the code a little bit?

Comment: Sure, I'll update with comments

Comment: Thanks I lot. I will try if this solves the problem I'm facing in my scenario.

Comment: Sounds good. If you have trouble, post what it is you're trying to store. You'll basically want to define a c# class to match the json structure you have, so that you can deserialize your page's result.

Comment: I'm facing a problem, I have a string and I'm converting it to string while saving it to JSON and I want to split it where ever I have \n in the string tell me how to do that?

Comment: Oh in javascript? You want an array from a newline-delimted string. You'd do something like `'new\nline'.split('\n')`, which would return an array like `["new", "line"]`.